# Accessing a render in a remote GUI instance

Tags: rendering, linux

I hit <kbd>F12</kbd> to start a huge render just before I left work on Friday. Now the render is ready, but Blender is just sitting there consuming a lot of memory. I'd like to get the render saved to disk, so I could kill the Blender process.

Is it possible to access a render that is sitting in a Blender instance on a remote Linux machine?

Comment: e.g. is there a way to make Blender to save its render results to temp space?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After your single image render has completed, there should be an **EXR file in your System Temp folder**, even if Blender has not formally outputted a frame image. However this is only the case if you have **enabled Save Buffers in the Render Performance panel** beforehand.

Check your Blender preferences for where that folder is on your Linux system (default path is **/tmp** for linux). The folder may be hidden, so you may have to unhide it to see it, but there should be an EXR file there until a system reboot or the folder is cleared for some other reason.

Alternatively, if your Blender app is running in GUI mode, you could possibly Remote Desktop into your Linux machine, and just save the image out of Blender.

Failing those 2 solutions, you may be out of luck, unfortunately.